# How fix "The requested URL was rejected" on backend octobercms

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm using octobercms in my hosting, and my website (theme) is working normally, the problem is being in the backend. I can access the backend correctly, however, when I try to register, update or delete any record I have the following return:

`The requested URL was rejected. If you think this is an error, please contact the webmaster. Your support ID is:`

I've already made several attempts to fix this problem, like clearing the browser cookies, I tried updating the octobercms, but nothing worked.

Comment: may be its because some security issue can you ask your hosting provide for logs, why my requests are rejected then you can know actual reason and solve it.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya I talked to my hosting, but they said it's problem in my code.

Comment: ok, can you ask them which code causing issue, they can provide you file name and line number of code.